# How should I give links to the same question many times and/or from different boards?

Tags: support, advertising, twitter

In order to gain publicist degree should/can I:

- use the same link?
- many times?
- in different non-twitter boards (forums, Emails, FB, etc.)?
- which one?

Update:
I thought it was clear from provided context (cited questions) that I was asking about gaining unique IP views per one published question for gaining the badge "Publicist"

Comment: Yes, my answer concerns the Publicist badge.

Comment: @waiwai933, thanks, I have write-only deficiency and syndrome.

Answer (score 1):

> use the same link?

You can use either the direct link button, or the shortened Twitter link (see below for details). You do not have to use the same link every time, since the Twitter link redirects to the link that credits your account.

> many times?

You can use either link in as many places as you want.

> in
>   different non-twitter boards (forums,
>   Emails, FB, etc.)?

You can use either link anywhere you want.

> which one?

You can use either linnk.

---

The direct link is located underneath your question:

[image]

To use the shortened Twitter link,

[image: twitter link]

Comment: In my browser (Chrome - I'm not sure if it's the same in others) to get the short link I have to right click the "link" portion and choose "Copy Link Address".