# My rep is not changing upon upvoting

Tags: support, meta

Usually I do not follow my score but in this cas the score was easy to remember - 400.

So, I noticed that my reputation has not changed upon upvoting of my question tomorning ["How should I give links to the same question many times and/or from different boards?"](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/698/how-should-i-give-links-to-the-same-question-many-times-and-or-from-different-boa)

Is it a bug or by design?

Comment: see http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/faq please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not gain or lose reputation on Meta. Meta reputation is copied over from your main account every hour.